# Is mixing java code and html/css unavoidable in this situation?

Tags: design-patterns

I have an app. that displays objects and tags related to these objects (not a very original app). One difference is that tags have "types". Most have the simple *type=object*, but others have *type=file*. Depending on the tag, they will have different renderings. For example clicking an *object tag* shows other objects that match, but on the file tag, you can get other files that match, or click a download link to download the file.

**I can do two things:**

From the JSP call a method (in the main application) that renders the data being provided (which includes the tag's text, its url etc) and returns a string of html. so if only an `object_id` and `object_name` are provided this method signature will result in the _object renderer_ being called, but if a `file_id`, `file_name` and `file_location` are provided the method signature will result in the _file renderer_ method being called. However these methods necessarily contain/know about the html to be rendered (mixing code/html) which is not ideal.

Or I could have some if statements within the jsp which determine what the data type is that is being returned and then display the appropriate HTML accordingly.

I prefer the first option, since at least more happens with the Java so I can unit test more stuff easily, but is there a way in which there is no mixing of code and html required (while still using vanilla servlets and not some new framework).

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Use jsp custom tags. Create your own taglib which would address these issues. IMO Custom tags come close to view model analogy in the world of JSPs